# Windows 7 Taskbar Never Combine, Show Labels Only, No Icon

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons, label

In Windows 7, in the Taskbar and Start Menu Properties, there is an option to Never Combine which shows both an icon and accompanying text. I have seen people who want Never Combine but want no labels. My problem is the opposite; I want to use Never Combine but hide the icon and keep the label, like how certain Linux desktop environments do.

UPDATE: The only things I have been able to find are to tediously use Resource Hacker to make every icon use a transparent icon OR switch to using LiteStep with an appropriate theme. I'm going to go with the latter option.